Dynamic prepared statement query for CQL in Java
I have to create CQL queries for multiple tables Java. An example of one such query is:
Statement select = QueryBuilder.select().all().from("MyKeySpace","MyTable")
                                        .where(QueryBuilder.eq("ID", id))
                                        .and(QueryBuilder.eq("NAME", name))
                                        .and(QueryBuilder.eq("STATUS", status))
                                        .and(QueryBuilder.eq("INPUT1", input1))
                                        .and(QueryBuilder.eq("INPUT2", input2))
                                        .allowFiltering();

The problem is that while all the column names are defined for each table, it's not necessary that all the inputs fields are specified by the user and some fields could be null. Thus, I want to create a query dynamically such that it includes only the columns where input is not null. I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this than defining multiple combinations based on non null inputs as that becomes infeasible as more inputs and queries get involved. I also wish to stick to prepared statements for security reasons.

One idea is to build your SQL prepared statement as a String.  You can put each column on a separate line and include the columns you want.

@GilbertLeBlanc That opens up a risk for SQL injection attacks so ideally I'd like to stick to prepared statements.

something like var building = QueryBuilder.select().all().from (...).where(...); if (name != nulll) building = building.and(QueryBuilder.eq("NAME", name)); if (status != nulll) building = building.and(QueryBuilder.eq("STATUS", status); ... var select = building.allowFiltering(); ?

( that is just the starting idea, more to correctly understand the question - obviously it can be improved by using some collection/mapping of column name to value(field?) )

@user85421 unfortunately, and statements could not be added to the query formed as Statement class in the first step.

as long as posted code snippet is Java, it will be possible to do as I suggested. Are you sure that where() is returning a Statement?

( in [not-too-old] Java  x = abc.def().ghi(); can be rewritten as var tmp = abc.def(); x = tmp.ghi(); [in Java 9 or older, you cannot use var and must use the real type instead, but basically same solution] - not valid if using some kind of pre-compiler or similar add-on that is extending Java's syntax - none of which is mentioned in the question )

probably you are using (an older version) of DataStax driver - information totally missing in question - QueryBuilder.select().all().from(...) and QueryBuilder.select().all().from(...).where(...) are documented to return Select.Where instances. These have the method and(), which returns a Select.Where itself, so can be used to call another and()

@user85421 Thanks, this looks about right! I think the problem was I was using a Statement as the type for select but since it's an abstract class, I can use Select.Where as the return type and and() would work for it! Please feel free to post it as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it and close the question.

As suggested by @user85421, the problem lies in using Statement as the type for select but since it's an abstract class, I can use Select.Where instead and append and() to the query later. This would look something like:
Select.Where select = QueryBuilder.select().all().from("MyKeySpace","MyTable")
                                           .where(QueryBuilder.eq("ID", id));
if (name != null) {
    select = select.and(QueryBuilder.eq("NAME", name));
}
...

